# cant update jasmine spy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

Hi I have a Angular service that uses another service that loads data from the local storage on init.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('localStorage', function ($window)
    {
        if (!$window.localStorage)
        {
            // throw Error
        }

        return $window.localStorage;
    });

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('session', function (localStorage)
    {
        var container = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sessionContainer'));

        return {
            getUser: getUser
        };
    });
```

Now i want to test the session service.

```
    describe('SessionService', function ()
    {
        var service;
        var localStorageMock;

         // Load the module.
        beforeEach(module('appRegistration'));

        // Create mocks.
        beforeEach(function ()
        {
            logMock = {};

            localStorageMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('localStorageServiceMockSpy', ['setItem', 'getItem']);
            localStorageMock.getItem.and.returnValue('{}');

            module(function ($provide)
            {
                $provide.value('localStorage', localStorageMock);
            });

            inject(function (_session_)
            {
                service = _session_;
            });
        });

        it('should call `getItem` on the `localStorageService` service', function ()
        {
            expect(localStorageMock.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sessionContainer');
        });

        describe('getUser method', function ()
        {
            it('should return an empty object when the user is not set', function ()
            {
                var result = service.getUser();

                expect(result).toEqual({});
            });

            it('should return the user data', function ()
            {
                // localStorageMock.getItem.and.returnValue('{"user":{"some":"data"}}');

                var result = service.getUser();

                expect(result).toEqual({some: 'user data'});
            });
        });

    });
```

As you can see in the `should return the user data` section.
I need a way to update the `container` so `getUser` returns the expected data.

I tried to update the `getItem` spy, but this does not work. The `localStorageMock` is already injected in the `session` service when i want to change the spy.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way is to have a variable with mocked value that is common for both function scopes:

```
    var getItemValue;
    beforeEach({
      localStorage: {
        getItem: jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(function () {
          return getItemValue;
        }),
        setItem: jasmine.createSpy()
      }
    });

    ...
        it('should return the user data', function ()
        {

            getItemValue = '{"user":{"some":"data"}}';

            inject(function (_session_) {
                service = _session_;
            });

            var result = service.getUser();

            expect(result).toEqual({some: 'user data'});
        });
```

Notice that `inject` should be moved from `beforeEach` to `it` for all specs (the specs that don't involve `getItemValue` may use shorter syntax, `it('...', inject(function (session) { ... }))`).

This reveals the flaw in service design that makes it test-unfriendly.

The solution is to make `container` lazily evaluated, so there is time to mock it after the app was bootstrapped with `inject`:

```
.factory('session', function (localStorage)
{
    var containerCache;

    function getUser() {
        ...
        return this.container;
    }
    return {
        get container() {
            return (containerCache === undefined)
                ? (containerCache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sessionContainer')))
                : containerCache;
        },
        getUser: getUser
    };
});
```

Additionally, this makes possible to test `session.container` as well. In this case `localStorageMock.getItem` spy value may be redefined whenever needed.

Comment: The simple solution is perfect. thanks.
You will get a up-vote if you change your answer to ES5

Comment: If you're about arrow function, they are good in examples for their readability, I replaced it with a normal one.